# Customizing the Wordpress login form

Tags: login, wp-login-form

using [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form) doc from WordPress I was able to remove the default WordPress logo and add my own using

```
function my_login_logo() { ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        #login h1 a, .login h1 a {
            background-image: url(<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/site-login-logo.png);
        height:65px;
        width:320px;
        background-size: 320px 65px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
        }
    </style>
<?php }
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_logo' );
```

The link to the WordPress site, not my site, is still there

```
<h1><a href="http://wordpress.org/" title="Powered by WordPress">Your Site Name</a></h1>
```

What I am wanting is more like this

```
<h1><a href="http://example.com/" title="<?PHP get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>"><?PHP get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
```

Comment: It seems you didn't read past the part where you can change the logo because right under it there is an explanation how to change the url
`function my_login_logo_url() {
    return home_url();
}
add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'my_login_logo_url' );`

Comment: oops my bad I totally skipped right over that part... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following filters in your `functions.php`

```
//wordpress.org > your link
function wp_305258_login_url() {
   return home_url();
}
add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'wp_305258_login_url' );

//alt text to your site name
function wp_305258_login_title() {
    return get_option( 'blogname' );
}
add_filter( 'login_headertitle', 'wp_305258_login_title' );
```